# Simple DataTable, BindingSource, DataGrid view shows no data

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have this super simple example, where I placed a DataGridView on a form, then with the follow code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var dt = new DataTable();
    var col = dt.Columns.Add("Column 1");
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = "test";

    var bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dt;

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

no rows in the Grid. I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a newly created row to the `DataTable.Rows` collection:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var col = dt.Columns.Add("Column 1");
var row = dt.NewRow();
row[0] = "test";
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: So calling `NewRow()` called on the `Table` instance doesn't add it to the collection?  I don't find that intuitive at all.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx) approves that: `You must use the NewRow method to create new DataRow objects with the same schema as the DataTable. After creating a DataRow, you can add it to the DataRowCollection...`

Comment: No argument from me, you're right, this is the answer (but I have to wait to accept it).

Comment: No problem. I've just clarified. :)